# Failed to build WebGL

Tags: unity

I'm using unity 5.2.2, and cannot build my project to WebGL. I have 3 DLLs in my project, all of which are built using .Net 3.5 and below. (`System.Drawing.dll, Newtonsoft.Json`, and a custom version of Libnoise-unity)

Here is the error I'm getting:

> `Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe -out "D:\Documents\UnityProjects\WarWorldInfinity\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\tempStrip" -l none -c link -x "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\native_link.xml" -f "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\LinkerDescriptors" -x "D:\Documents\UnityProjects\WarWorldInfinity/Temp/StagingArea/Data/methods_pointedto_by_uievents.xml" -d "D:\Documents\UnityProjects\WarWorldInfinity\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed" -a "D:\Documents\UnityProjects\WarWorldInfinity\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" -a "D:\Documents\UnityProjects\WarWorldInfinity\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll"`
>
> `stdout: Fatal error in Mono CIL Linker System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromPreserveAttribute.IsPreserveAttribute (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference arg) [0x00000] in :0 at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromPreserveAttribute.m_0 (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute c) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[CustomAttribute] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate) [0x00000] in :0 at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromPreserveAttribute.HasPreserveAttribute (ICustomAttributeProvider type) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Linq.Enumerable+c_Iterator1E`1[Mono.Cecil.PropertyDefinition].MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveStep.MarkProperties (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, IEnumerable`1 properties) [0x00000] in :0 at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromPreserveAttribute.ProcessType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Boolean assemblyHasPreserveAttribute) [0x00000] in :0 at UnusedBytecodeStripper2.ResolveFromPreserveAttribute.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run () [0x00000] in :0 at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriver (Mono.Linker.Driver driver) [0x00000] in :0 stderr:`
>
> `UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:66) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1, String&, String&, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:192) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:185) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:136) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String[], String[], String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:121) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable, String, String[], String[], String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:444) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:StripAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:417) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:291) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:218) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess(BuildTarget, String, String, String, Int32, Int32, String, String, BuildOptions, RuntimeClassRegistry)`

Comment: You have some errors in your code. Need to fix them before attempting to generate build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the System.Drawing reference in Libnoise that was causing it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you are trying to build with a featureset that is not yet compatible with WebGL builds.

For example, if you try to add a Networking component and build to WebGL, you will get that same error about UnusedByteCodeStripper2.

Comment: Thanks, Unity. That is an amazingly useful way to signal to a developer what their mistake is. </sarcasm>

Comment: Heh, well to Unity's defense the WebGL build is still not ready for prime time.  You should expect problems at this point in time.

Comment: Well I'm using the System.Net UDP classes.